# Search NetSuite Custom Record Type in PHP

Tags: php, netsuite, suitetalk

I have a Custom Record Type and I am having trouble searching the barcode from the item value:

[image]

I am using the NetSuite PHPToolkit_2015_2 and this stackoverflow answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13366947/2120512 and http://burnignorance.com/netsuite-tips-and-hacks/working-with-custom-records-in-suitetalk/ to attempt to build this request:

```
$service = new NetSuiteService();
// Perform an AdvancedSearch for Items
// https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/12203/kw/php%20search%20criteria

$service->setSearchPreferences(false, 1000, false);
$savedSearchId = 'customsearch_barcode_view'; //customsearch## from UI ID field
$searchAdvanced = new CustomRecordSearchAdvanced();
setFields($searchAdvanced, array('savedSearchScriptId'=>$savedSearchId));

$request = new SearchRequest();
$request->searchRecord = $searchAdvanced;

// PHP Toolkit 2012.2: Sample Code to Perform Search that Uses a Custom Field as Filter
// https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/25066/kw/php%20custom%20field

$custSearchField = new SearchMultiSelectCustomField();
$custSearchField->value = new ListOrRecordRef();
$custSearchField->value->internalId = "custrecord_barcode_item";
$custSearchField->value->value = "00001 Beer Mug";

$searchAdvanced->customFieldList = $custSearchField;

$results = $service->search($request);
```

I still get all the results for the Custom Record Type and never able to figure out how to search by the item. I have made changes and still receive the entire results.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this won't immediately solve your problem, but at the first glance I can see an error in your code.

The customFieldList is of type array, so you need to change this:

```
$searchAdvanced->customFieldList = $custSearchField;
```

To this

```
$searchAdvanced->customFieldList = [$custSearchField];
```